# How to use https and http on the same website via nginx-proxy-manager

Tags: docker, nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy

Setup:

- Docker (compose) (everywhere same network)

  - nginx-proxy-manager (probably from here we must change / add some
    additional nginx config to app-1)
  - app-1-nginx (site.conf)
  - app-1-php

Hello,
how we can force turn off ssl for specific location on website?
Whole website using https version of protocol, but we need turn off it for specific location and use only http.

I quess we need write something into the "Custom Nginx Configuration". But what?

Thank You